# will non-daemon python threads exit after they're done with their task?

Tags: python, multithreading, io

**Context:** I've got a simple python script that writes a bunch of files to s3 (~70-100) every few seconds.  Because its I/O bound, I wanted to thread the write process so the script performs better.  I'm using `threading` to build my threads.

**Question:** Since my threads are a) non-daemons and b) they only have 1 task to perform (write a file), if I loop over my list of threads and call `.join()` will they finish their task and exit gracefully? Do I even need to call `join()` here or will they just exit when they're done? I *believe* join() is the way to go here but since i'm very new to python, I don't know what I don't know....

Here's some simplified code for reference:

```
buildOutput() #calls the section below 
for thread in threads:
   thread.join()
time.sleep(60)
```

calls:

```
  for item in out[fileRoot]: 
        #write individiual files
        key = findKey(item, FILE_KEY)
        full_key = FILE_PATH + str(key) + FILE_TYPE
        t = FileWriter(item, full_key)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t) #global threads list for the script
```

where FileWriter is the class that does the writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join makes sure that the main thread will wait until joined thread finishes its task. There is a good ascii art given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading).

So you'd better use join when your child threads are performing I/O to prevent any unexpected behavior.

Comment: right but what happens to the thread when its done with its task?  are there any mechanisms by which I can be sure that nothing is floating around like a zombie process or garbage collection concerns? something like that?

Comment: treated like any other method, deleted from stack. Since we are talking about threads there won't be anything like a zombie process because as you said they finish their task. However, without join, if the main thread exits while the other haven't  finished, their stack will remain (not good).