# Not able to write using xlsxwriter when I use threading

Tags: python, multithreading, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write location's address to my excel sheet using xlswriter package in python. The problem I am facing is when I try to run the function using a thread the values are not written to the worksheet. See the below code: Here rows a list containing all the raw address.

```
import threading
import xlsxwriter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
outputLocation = 'output.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outputLocation)
w_sheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet('openstreet')

def openstreet():
    p = 1
    for row in rows:        #rows consists of raw addresses

        try:
            rawAddress = str(" ".join(row[1].strip().split())) #here I am normalizing the addresses using openstreet api
            location = geolocator.geocode(rawAddress)
            w_sheet4.write(p, 1, rawAddress)
            w_sheet4.write(p, 2, str(location.address))
        except Exception as e:
            print "OpenStreet", e

        p += 1

t4 = threading.Thread(target=openstreet)
t4.start()
```

I am able to write to the worksheet if I don't use thread and run the function by calling it. See the below code:

```
import threading
import xlsxwriter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
outputLocation = 'output.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outputLocation)
w_sheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet('openstreet')

def openstreet():
    p = 1
    for row in rows:        #rows consists of raw addresses

        try:
            rawAddress = str(" ".join(row[1].strip().split())) #here I am normalizing the addresses using openstreet api
            location = geolocator.geocode(rawAddress)
            w_sheet4.write(p, 1, rawAddress)  #raw address
            w_sheet4.write(p, 2, str(location.address)) #normalize address
        except Exception as e:
            print "OpenStreet", e

        p += 1

#t4 = threading.Thread(target=openstreet)
#t4.start()
openstreet()
```

The reason I am using thread because I am using multiple APIs (google, yahoo, openstreetmap API , bing) trying to normalize addresses and compare them. Could anyone help me why I am not able to write to the worksheet when I use thread instead of normal function calling.

Comment: I forgot to add use threading.join in my program. I have answered by question below.

Comment: You may need to add `workbook.close()` to write the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Use with caution! XlsxWriter is not thread safe. I discovered that if you use in_memory option it will use SharedStrings and eventually write to unexpected cells. I've created a ticket atm:

[Github discussion](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/334)

*Update from XlsxWriter author:*

> The `_get_shared_string_index()` method in `SharedStrings` isn't
>   thread safe. The other methods in that class should be since they are
>   only called from `Workbook` (for which there should only be one unique
>   instance per xlsxwriter object) or via the `Workbook` destructor (when
>   the worksheet threads should be joined and activity stopped).
>
> > i've discovered that if i use in_memory option XlsxWriter will use SharedStrings
>
> The SharedStrings class can be called regardless of whether you use
>   in_memory or not. The in_memory option relates to the use of temporary
>   files and not SharedStrings (see the docs).
>
> If you wish to avoid using SharedStrings, and thus avoid locking, you
>   can use the constant_memory mode. There are some caveats to that
>   though: data needs to be written in row-column order and you can't use
>   add_table() or merge_range(). See the Contructor docs (link above) and
>   also Working with Memory and Performance.
>
> > And is there anything else in XlsxWriter that i need to worry about?
>
> Possibly, but nothing that springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using threading.join() at the end of the function. Why we need to use join() can be understood from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138219/use-of-threading-thread-join). The below code is working for me.

```
import threading
import xlsxwriter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
outputLocation = 'output.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outputLocation)
w_sheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet('openstreet')

def openstreet():
    p = 1
    for row in rows:        #rows consists of raw addresses

        try:
            rawAddress = str(" ".join(row[1].strip().split())) #here I am normalizing the addresses using openstreet api
            location = geolocator.geocode(rawAddress)
            w_sheet4.write(p, 1, rawAddress)
            w_sheet4.write(p, 2, str(location.address))
        except Exception as e:
            print "OpenStreet", e

        p += 1

t4 = threading.Thread(target=openstreet)
t4.start()
t4.join() #we need to use threading.join to make sure the thread function finishes before the main program exits
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown that explains why you need to call `t4.join()` since that should happen anyway since `t4` is a non-daemon thread.  Note you're not actually calling the `join` method because there's no `()` at the end. Anyway, there must be other things going on in your real code not shown here.