# What does sys.exit really do with multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, exit

I was really confused by sys.exit() in python.
In [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), it says "Exit from Python"; does that mean when `sys.exit()` is called in a python program, the process will exit? If so, the code below shows a different result:

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def threadrun():
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t=threading.Thread(target=threadrun)
    t.start()
    sys.exit()
```

Launching this program in linux, result was not the expected one as python documentation says but still run in the system, so what does `sys.exit()` really do?

Comment: it waits for the thread to finish, the thread does not finish so it doesn't close, were you expecting it to forcefully stop the thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the documentation [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) raises `SystemExit`:

> Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).

If `SystemExit` reaches the [default exception handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/836b6421484cbbe3de105d9c7cec9371422d1397/Python/pythonrun.c##L1170),
it calls `handle_system_exit()`, which more or less pushes through to [`Py_Finalize()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/836b6421484cbbe3de105d9c7cec9371422d1397/Python/pythonrun.c#L411), which in turn calls [`wait_for_thread_shutdown()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/836b6421484cbbe3de105d9c7cec9371422d1397/Python/pythonrun.c#L419) in Python 2, so `sys.exit()` is the same as the normal *falling off the bottom of the main module* in waiting for all non-daemon threads to terminate.

Answer (score 15):

<sub>(Paraphrasing what's in the Python 2 documentation for [Thread Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects))</sub>

Normally a Python program exits only when there's nothing but daemon<sup>✶</sup>
threads (ignoring itself) left running. The “main thread” object which corresponds to the initial thread of control in the program *isn't* a daemon thread. Threads created using `threading.Thread` inherit their daemonic status from the creating thread, so if that's the main thread, they will also be non-daemonic.

This means that *by default* any threads created and started by your main program will prevent it from exiting if they are still running when the main thread is terminated (by `sys.exit()` or simply by just hitting the end of its code). In other words, the program exits only when no alive **non‑daemon** threads (i.e. only daemon threads) are left.

You can override this default behavior by explicitly setting<sup>✶✶</sup> the
`daemon` property of any
created thread objects to `True` *before* starting it.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=threadrun)
    t.daemon = True  # Explicitly set property.
    t.start()
    sys.exit()
```

Which will allow the program to actually end when `sys.exit()` is called (although calling it explicitly like that would not be necessary since presumably the code above would be at the end of the script anyway).

---

<sup>✶</sup> A daemon thread is one that runs in the background and does not prevent the interpreter from exiting. See [Daemon Threads Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation).

<sup>✶✶</sup> In Python 3.3, a *`daemon`* keyword argument with a default value of `None` was added to the `Thread`
[class constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)
which means that, starting from that version onwards, you can simply use:

```
    # Sets whether the thread is daemonic via "daemon" keyword argument.
    t = threading.Thread(target=threadrun, daemon=True)
```

However, doing it separately via an explicit attribute assignment statement
still works, and would therefore be the more version-portable way of
doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the end of the program is when the last thread will be terminated. Maybe kind of join() method(like in Java) in python will wait for other threads.

Please, read this article(: there is a good explanation how to play with threads in your case
[Use of threading.Thread.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138219/use-of-threading-thread-join)

and

documentation
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html (but relax, it is only for additional knowledge.

and read this article about daemon property(if you do not want to wait for others threads become terminated
[Meaning of daemon property on Python Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330111/python-thread-daemon-property)