# How to stop daemon thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a simple producer consumer application.

The producer is a thread that writes stuff to a queue and a consumer is a thread that reads the messages from the queue does stuff and at some points exits.

my producer looks a little bit like this

```
def producer(queue):
    while not queue.full():
        queue.put(randint(1, 199))
```

and the consumer

```
def consumer(queue):
    for i in range(100):
        print(queue.get())
        queue.task_done()
```

in my main I invoke those threads like that

```
p = Thread(target=producer)
c = Thread(target=consumer)

p.daemon = True
p.start()
c.start()
c.join()
```

when `c` finishes the only remaining non deamon thread is main, what is the proper way to end those threads?

**update**

Here is the exact code that my producer is using, since the consumer is exiting and the problem lies with the producer

```
def generate_random_alphanumerics(msg_queue):
    while True:
        if not msg_queue.full():
            msg_queue.put(hashlib.sha1(bytes(randint(1, 10000))).hexdigest() * 10)
        else:
            sleep(0.01)
```

is the problem that the thread is sleeping?

Comment: You don't have to stop daemon threads. They will be terminated automatically when the main thread ends. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804988/what-does-sys-exit-really-do-with-multiple-threads/38805873#38805873) of mine for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: but still the program hangs instead of exiting

Comment: even if I add `sys.exit()` which shouldn't be needed

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee: I suspect you're omitting critical parts of your code then. If you correctly set the thread as a `daemon` before `start`ing it, it should require no special contortions to exit.

Comment: LetsPlayYahtzee: No, you shouldn't need to call `sys.execit()` explicitly. The sample code in your question must not be an accurate representation of your real code. Please [edit] it after reading [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that the producer loop never ends, so you should have a way to tell it to stop.

```
stop_event= threading.Event()
p = Thread(target=producer, args=(msg_queue, stop_event))
p.start()
```

And the producer becomes:

```
def generate_random_alphanumerics(msg_queue, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        if not msg_queue.full():
            [...]
```

Then, when you want to stop the producer just do:

```
stop_event.set()
```

Comment: great answer, I must have been blind or this was not mentioned anywhere in so simple terms

Comment: This is by far the most simple way to stop a thread anywhere on SO