# control a daemon thread with routes in flask

Tags: python, multithreading

How do you make two routes control a daemon thread in python

flask backend file

```
from flask import Flask 
from time import time,sleep
from threading import Thread


app = Flask(__name__)

def intro():
    while True:
        sleep(3)
        print (f" Current time : {time()}")


@app.route('/startbot')
def start_bot():
    global bot_thread 
    bot_thread = Thread(target=intro, daemon=True)
    bot_thread.start()
    return "bot started " 

@app.route('/stopbot')
def stop_bot():
    bot_thread.join()
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When trying to kill the thread the curl request in the terminal does not return back to the console and the thread keeps on printing data to the terminal

the idea I had was that I would declare the variable that holds the reference to the bot_thread and use the routes to control it
to test this I used `curl http://localhost:port/startbot` and `curl http://localhost:port/stopbot`

I can start the bot just fine but when I try to kill it, I get the following

```
NameError: name 'bot_thread' is not defined
```

Any help and does and don'ts will be very appreciated

take into consideration that after killing the thread a user can create a new one and also be able to kill it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :

```py
from threading import Thread


def intro():
    print("hello")


global bot_thread


def start_bot():
    bot_thread = Thread(target=intro, daemon=True)
    return

def stop_bot():
    if bot_thread:
        bot_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    start_bot()  # simulating a request on it
    time.sleep(1)  # some time passes ...
    stop_bot()  # simulating a request on it
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so71056246.py", line 25, in <module>
    stop_bot()  # simulating a request on it
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so71056246.py", line 17, in stop_bot
    if bot_thread:
NameError: name 'bot_thread' is not defined
```

My [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) makes the error visually clear for me : the `bot_thread` is not used, because it is a local variable, not the `global` one, although they have the same name. This is a pitfall for Python programmers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/11384184) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693120/11384184) for example.

So :

```py
def start_bot():
    global bot_thread
    bot_thread = Thread(target=intro, daemon=True)
    return
```

but

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so71056246.py", line 26, in <module>
    stop_bot()  # simulating a request on it
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so71056246.py", line 19, in stop_bot
    bot_thread.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1048, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started
```

Hence :

```py
def start_bot():
    global bot_thread
    bot_thread = Thread(target=intro, daemon=True)
    bot_thread.start()
    return
```

which finally gives :

```
hello
```

---

**EDIT**

> When trying to kill the thread the curl request in the terminal does not return back to the console and the thread keeps on printing data to the terminal

@prometheus the `bot_thread` runs the `intro` function. Because it contains an infinite loop (`while True`) it will never reach the end of the function (implicit `return`) so the thread is never considered as finished. Because of that, when the main thread tries to `join` (wait until the thread finishes, then get the result), it waits endlessly because the bot thread is stuck in the loop.
So you have to make it possible to exit the `while` loop. For example (like in the example I linked in a comment), by using another `global` variable, a [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_flag), that gets set in the main thread (route `stop_bot`) and that is checked in the `intro` loop. Like so :

```py
from time import time, sleep
from threading import Thread


def intro():
    global the_bot_should_continue_running
    while the_bot_should_continue_running:
        print(time())
        sleep(1)


global bot_thread
global the_bot_should_continue_running


def start_bot():
    global bot_thread, the_bot_should_continue_running
    bot_thread = Thread(target=intro, daemon=True)
    the_bot_should_continue_running = True  # before the `start` !
    bot_thread.start()
    return

def stop_bot():
    if bot_thread:
        global the_bot_should_continue_running
        the_bot_should_continue_running = False
        bot_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_bot()  # simulating a request on it
    sleep(5.5)  # some time passes ...
    stop_bot()  # simulating a request on it
```

prints 6 times then exits.

Comment: i don;t think you get the idea , please check the updated code

Comment: @prometheus You do not get a response because the `bot_thread.join()` blocks until the thread ends, which it will never do because it is running in an infinite loop. Either terminate the thread, or use another `global` variable to indicate to it that it should stop (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41139707/11384184)).

Comment: can you explain how to do that properly

Comment: @prometheus see the edit in my answer

Comment: worked but how good is this solution out of 10 what if someone keeps sending a request to `/startbot` route isn't that going to cause the server to crash because it will consume all resources

Comment: @prometheus if someone keeps calling `startbot` it will create many threads, indeed. If you want to ensure there is only one thread at any time, you can modify `startbot` to check if `global bot_thread` is None  and in this case create the thread, otherwise doing nothing. and when the thread has been `join`ed, setting the `global bot_thread` back to `None`, so that it can be `startbot`ed again.