# How to check for mouse movement outside of tkinter GUI mainloop?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

To understand threadding better I try to write a clicker with a small tkinter GUI, which only clicks when you don't move the mouse. I have created a working script without noise (labels that show duration, clicks, settings etc.) that runs a deamon permanently in the background to detect mouse movements:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from win32api import SetCursorPos, mouse_event, GetCursorPos
from win32con import MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP
from threading import Thread, Lock


class ClickerGUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.mouse_x_coord, self.mouse_y_coord = 1, 1
        self.cursor_pos = GetCursorPos()
        self.mouse_moving = False
        self.click_intervall = 3000
        self.start_stop_btn = Button(self, text='Start', font='Calibri 12', width=15, command=self.run_clicker)
        self.start_stop_btn.pack(pady=10)
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.check_mouse_movement)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def run_clicker(self):
        self.running = not self.running
        if self.running:
            self.start_stop_btn.config(text='Stop')
            self.click()
        else:
            self.start_stop_btn.config(text='Start')

    def click(self):
        if self.running:
            if not self.mouse_moving:
                print('Click')  # Debug print
                # click to coordinates and set mous back to last position
                SetCursorPos((self.mouse_x_coord, self.mouse_y_coord))
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, self.mouse_x_coord, self.mouse_y_coord, 0, 0)
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, self.mouse_x_coord, self.mouse_y_coord, 0, 0)
                SetCursorPos(self.cursor_pos)
                # put GUI in focus
                self.focus_force()
            self.after(self.click_intervall, self.click)

    def check_mouse_movement(self):
        with self.lock:
            print(self.mouse_moving)  # Debug print
            if self.cursor_pos != GetCursorPos():
                self.cursor_pos = GetCursorPos()
                self.mouse_moving = True
            else:
                self.mouse_moving = False
        self.after(self.click_intervall//20, self.check_mouse_movement)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli = ClickerGUI()
    cli.mainloop()
```

But now I would like to run the deamon only when the clicker is active, thus starting and stopping the thread. I found this [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131117/how-to-stop-daemon-thread) very interesting but am not sure if this event logic matches my aproach since I am not using a loop but rather a recursive function call. How can I implement this or is this approach even recommendable at all?

Is there an even better/more save solution or totally diffenent approach to implement this functionality?

Comment: You don't need to run `check_mouse_movement()` using thread since `.after()` is used inside the function.

Comment: Now I feel dumb! Turns out I can just call `check_mouse_movement()` with `click()` from inside `run_clicker()` and wrap its `.after()` call with `if self.running:` to only continue it while the clicker is running. Tanks for the hint!