# Watchdog observer method

Tags: python, methods, python-watchdog

I am new to python and watchdog, and was confused by the quickstart example. In the example, there is a block of code like this:

```
self.observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
except:
    self.observer.stop()
    print('Error')

self.observer.join()
```

I couldn't find any documentations about the `start`, `stop` and `join` method. Also, although knowing that the while loop inside try except probably makes the observer run for every 5 seconds, I don't understand how does it work?

Could anyone explain me what do the three methods do and how does the loop work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I corrected my answer based on @Amit Gupta's post.

---

After some research I found that all three methods belong to threading.Thread object.

`self.observer.start()` creates a new thread,

`While True:
       time.sleep(1)` keeps main thread running

When program stop, `self.observer.stop()` does some work before the thread terminate. (@Amit Gupta)

`self.observer.join()` is needed to proper end a thread for "it blocks the thread in which you're making the call, until (`self.observer`) is finished." as said by Erik Allik in [Use of threading.Thread.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138219/use-of-threading-thread-join)

Answer (score 1):

threading.Thread does not provide any implementation for stop(). Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482230/why-does-the-python-threading-thread-object-has-start-but-not-stop).
Stop() here is specific to Observer and in this example code it will stop the thread on receiving an exception.
Rest of the stuff that you have written is correct.