# Python: Why 2 calls of the same function don't run in parallel?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to call the same function with different parameters in parallel using `multiprocessing` module.

Here is example of my code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CurrencyRatesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'currency_rates'

    def ready(self):
        import time
        from multiprocessing import Process

        import currency_rates.ws_get_rates

        p1 = Process(currency_rates.ws_get_rates.get_rates('1m', 'tBTCUSD', 'BTC2USD'))
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(currency_rates.ws_get_rates.get_rates('1m', 'tIOTUSD', 'IOT2USD'))
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

But it doesn't work. I see just p1's execution result.

NOTE: `get_rates()` uses `websocket` module.

Could somebody describe what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe p1.join() will block until p1 returns. Then p2 would resume.

Comment: That doesn't block the other processes, only this one

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138327/5476782
if you don't need join(), remove it from your code, it blocks the thread in execution

Comment: @Karlos there's no code after the joins, nothing is being blocked from running. There was an answer here a minute ago that seems plausible about the work carried out by get_rates which is called in the current process and is therefore not parallel

Comment: the code after doesn't matter. With join you block the thread which lauched the p2, so no answer from p2. Have a look at https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: @Karlos , even without join() p2 doesn't start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Process arguments. Modify it as follows:

This demo *does* work. Not sure why the specific issue is not resolved for OP.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import sys

def outputString(thestring):
    for i in range(3):
        print(thestring)
        time.sleep(2)
    return

def main():
    p1 = Process(target=outputString, args=('P1 is processing',))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=outputString, args=('P2 is processing',))
    p2.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

OP original code (modified)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CurrencyRatesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'currency_rates'

    def ready(self):
        import time
        from multiprocessing import Process

        import currency_rates.ws_get_rates

        p1 = Process(target=currency_rates.ws_get_rates.get_rates, args=('1m', 'tBTCUSD', 'BTC2USD'))
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target=currency_rates.ws_get_rates.get_rates, args=('1m', 'tIOTUSD', 'IOT2USD'))
        p2.start()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Probably because I'm using `websocket` module in `get_rates()`

Comment: Meaning it still blocks? Not sure how unless all resources on the machine are consumed by `get_rates()` because they run in completely different process space. But you can't have the join() in their, or it will not work in parallel.