# Why is .join() method called .join() in the threading module?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

This is a rather silly question...yet it bugs the heck out of me. In the `threading` module we have a `Thread.join()` method.
I understand that it blocks the calling thread, but why is `.join()` called 'join'?  Why is it not called `main_thread_wait` or `block_parent_thread` or something like that?

Every time I see `.join()`, I feel the child thread is joining something to get caclulations done. Is there some reason why this particular keyword was chosen for a method name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345418/the-join-function-in-threading . First answer.

And a visual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading

Comment: The name is copied from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html), which I believe copied it from various Unixy threading implementations written before threading was standardized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This name is far older than Python.  It appears in the POSIX threading library (libpthread) as [**`pthread_join()`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) (the "pthread" prefix is used because C has no namespaces).  However, for process level concurrency, both [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) and [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) use the name `wait()`.

Other parts of the pthread library do use the term wait, but usually for higher-level synchronization primitives, such as [`pthread_barrier_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) or [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html).  I imagine that `pthread_wait()` would have been ambiguous between "wait for [some synchronization object]" and "wait for a thread to terminate."

Answer (score 1):

The child-thread joins the parent. `Thread.start` makes the parent give birth to a thread and let it free. `Thread.join` makes the parent block (wait) until the child is done doing its job.

You can imagine it like this:

- the parent thread is a mighty god that can live for a long time
- with `Thread.start` it gives birth to a mortal
- right after its birth, the mortal runs away and starts living its own life (executing its `run` method)
- the god may continue minding his own business
- he also may want to take a look at his offspring, to see whether, literally, it `is_alive`
- he also may start observing the whole life of the offspring, waiting for him to come back, right until the death of the latter (this is the `join` method). While doing that, the god cannot do anything else, because he enjoys admiring his creature so much (the call to `join` blocks the parent thread), but after the mortal dies, the god can continue his life