# Create instance of a Thread class within the same file in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to create an instance of a `Thread` type class called `A` within the class `B` that's in the same file.

I tried some combinations `x = A(i)`, `x = A.A(i)`, `x = A.__init(i)` and so on...

```
from threading import Thread

class A(Thread):
    def __init__(self, i)
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i

    def run(self):
        print('foo')

class B()
    def __init__(self):
        x = #instance of A ?
        x.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    B() # Here I call the class B that should start the thread of A
```

I need to call the class. And not a method inside the class. Because I want then to call the `x.start()` method to start the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `x.start()` like you show.  Just make sure to call `x.join()` from `B.__init__` -- this is the main thread.  In general, you want the main thread to 'wait' or 'join' on all sub threads.  Here is a working example:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> import time
>>>
>>> class A(Thread):
...
...    def __init__(self, i):
...        Thread.__init__(self)
...        self._index = i
...        
...    def run(self):
...        time.sleep(0.010)
...        for i in range(self._index):
...            print('Thread A running with index i: %d' % i)
...            time.sleep(0.100)
...            
>>>
>>> class B(object):
...    
...    def __init__(self, index):
...        x = A(i=index)
...        print ('starting thread.')
...        x.start()
...        print('waiting ...')
...        x.join()
...        print('Thread is complete.')
...        
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...    B(10) # Here I call the class B that should start the thread of A
starting thread.
waiting ...
Thread A running with index i: 0
Thread A running with index i: 1
Thread A running with index i: 2
Thread A running with index i: 3
Thread A running with index i: 4
Thread A running with index i: 5
Thread A running with index i: 6
Thread A running with index i: 7
Thread A running with index i: 8
Thread A running with index i: 9
Thread is complete.
```

Last note, there is no reason that `A.__init__` can't call `start()` on itself (instead of `B.__init__` doing it) -- that's just a matter of style.  The only really key thing is that the main thread should in best practice wait or join on all subthreads -- if you don't do this you can get strange behavior in certain applications as the main thread exits before sub-threads.   See this:

- [what is the use of join() in python threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading)

for more.

Comment: It's weird... I get `NameError: name 'A' is not defined` in mine... But If I copy your code in another file it works. Names are exact... I'm trying to find whats wrong. Maybe class declaration order in the code its important ???

Comment: LOL... The problem was the order of class declarations. I declared the `Thread` class after the other. Switched them and It works now ! Thank you !