# how do you make threads wait for eachother

Tags: python, multithreading

okay so i'm trying to make a speedtest in python and the only problem i am having is that i cant figure out how to make the download speed threads finish before starting the upload speed threads. i can provide some of my code:

```py
t1 = Thread(target= dload)
t2 = Thread(target= testo)
t3 = Thread(target= uload)
t4 = Thread(target= testo2)

t2.daemon=True
t4.daemon=True

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
```

i need `t1` and `t2` to end first, and then `t3` and `t4` should start. `t2` is a daemon here because i want it to end as soon as `t1` is done. forgot to mention that beforehand. i am completely new to threading so if this is really wrong please forgive me.

Comment: For example `t1.join()` will wait until `t1` is done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of join() in Python threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading)

Comment: well i tried to use join but i dont dont know how that would help. since i need the 4 threads to activate in pairs. is there a way to make that happen using join?

Answer (score 1):

You use `join` for that. Note that `t2.daemon=True` means that you expect `t2` to not end while the script is running. This is in opposition to your specification that you want to wait for t2 to end.

```
t1 = Thread(target= dload)
t2 = Thread(target= testo)
t3 = Thread(target= uload)
t4 = Thread(target= testo2)

# t2.daemon=True
t4.daemon=True

t1.start()
t2.start()

# wait for t1 and t2 to end
t1.join()
t2.join()

t3.start()
t4.start()
```

Comment: t2 is a daemon here because i dont want t2 to end until t1 ends. i might have given too little info in my question. sorry for that!

Comment: @Undergod, That's not what "daemon" means. A daemon thread is a thread that the system will automatically kill (with no warning!) as soon as the last non-daemon thread in the program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem:

- Using `.join` method. (*Effective and clean*)
- Using functions (*Not as effective than `.join`*)

1. Using `.join` function : see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555599/16187613).
2. Using function:

   - The basic idea is threading one function and just calling the other function.
   - And if you want to run `testo` until t1 ends, then you can watch a variable and run the inside while loop. for example:

```
while t1_ends==False: # Change this value to true in t1 fucntion at the end of it.
    testo()
```

```
t1 = Thread(target= dload)
t2 = Thread(target= testo)
t3 = Thread(target= uload)
t4 = Thread(target= testo2)

t4.daemon=True
def a():
    t1.start()
    testo()
def b():
    t3.start()
    t4.start()

a()
b()
```